# Add frontend editor with media buttons for Visitors and display only their media

Tags: uploads, media-library, wp-editor

I'm trying to make a frontend blog post submit for registered users. I have this working without media, now trying to add media.

The standard `wp_editor`

```
$content = '';
$editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';
$settings = array( 'media_buttons' => true);
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );
```

doesn't seem to display the media button for Visitors. How can I show the Add media button for Visitors?

Also, I would need to show each user only his uploaded media. How is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

```
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
```

Is useless define the setting's array if you dont call it :D